# What is the best way to add custom JS functions in a file into Svelte app?

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, auth0, svelte

What is the best way to add a JS file into Svelte app?

I will add custom javascript functions for authentication with Auth0 and I am trying to do the easiest way using Svelte architecture. Any suggestions?

I have done authentication with Netlify identity but I am now willing to do that with Auth0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `import`:

```js
<script>
   import thing from './your-thing.js';
</script>
```